# UPDATE NO DOCTRINE-MODULE

Tags: php, doctrine

Para eu gerar o mapa da base de dados uso esse código:

```
doctrine-module orm:convert:mapping --force --from-database --namespace="Application\Entity\\" annotation C:\www\projetoBd\module\Application\src
```

Para gerar as entidades:

```
doctrine-module orm:generate:entities C:\www\projetoBd\module\Application\src
```

Para setar o caminho do repositório, substituir `@ORM\Entity` por `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Entity\Repository\Pessoa")`

Para gerar o repositório:

```
doctrine-module orm:generate:repositories C:\www\projetoBd\module\Application\src
```

Agora meu problema: criei meu banco, por exemplo, tabela `nome`, tabela `endereco` e segui esses passos de cima. Mas agora eu criei a tabela `telefone`. Qual o comando que eu uso para dar esse update?? Seria algo parecido como `doctrine-module orm:update` ou coisa parecida??

Obrigado galera.